# Cómo correr una lista en un query de mysql

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

Tengo un programa en tkinter en el que se selecciona un rango de fechas y ese rango luego es pasado por un query en mysql para sacar los datos que tengan esa fecha. **Nota: El formato del output del DateEntry es el mismo que el de la columna de fechas en mysql.** Se que no es un error de formato, de hecho ya hice el query con una sola fecha. El problema es que las fechas salen en una lista y la terminal me arroja:   **Failed processing format-parameters; Python 'list' cannot be converted to a MySQL type**

Aquí dejo el código, si alguien sabe cómo resolverlo, gracias.

```
ventana=customtkinter.CTk()
ventana.geometry("700x500")

def date_range(start,stop):
    global dates # If you want to use this outside of functions
     
    dates = []
    diff = (stop-start).days
    for i in range(diff+1):
        day = start + timedelta(days=i)
        dates.append(day.strftime("%m/%d/%Y"))
    if dates:
    
        print(dates) # Print it, or even make it global to access it outside this
    

date1 =DateEntry(ventana)
date1.grid(column=1, row=1, padx=10,pady=10)

date2 =DateEntry(ventana)
date2.grid(column=2, row=1, padx=10,pady=10)

def query():
    date_range(date1.get_date(), date2.get_date())
    fechas=dates
    conn=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="Baelca1", database="Lista_datos_Baelca")
    cursor1=conn.cursor()
    comando="SELECT * FROM ticket WHERE Fecha=%s"
    parametro=(fechas, )
    cursor1.execute(comando, parametro)
    print(cursor1.fetchall)

boton=customtkinter.CTkButton(ventana, command=query) 
boton.grid()  


ventana.mainloop()
```

Dejo también el output de las fechas:

> ['11/01/2022', '11/02/2022', '11/03/2022', '11/04/2022', '11/05/2022',
> '11/06/2022', '11/07/2022', '11/08/2022', '11/09/2022', '11/10/2022',
> '11/11/2022', '11/12/2022', '11/13/2022', '11/14/2022', '11/15/2022',
> '11/16/2022', '11/17/2022', '11/18/2022', '11/19/2022', '11/20/2022',
> '11/21/2022', '11/22/2022']

Comment: Ahora te doy una respuesta, ya que tengo tiempo. Pero primero, dos consejos: 1- Tu pregunta. en el fondo, no tiene nada que ver con Tkinter (a pesar de que piensas ponerlo en tkinter), si no solamente con Python y MySql. Las etiquetas deben ser algo que no debe faltar ni haber de más. Como habrás notado, esta etiqueta está muy ignorada. Asi que con más razón quitarla. La quitaría yo, pero tu código tiene la parte de customtkinter. Te recomiendo quitar la etiqueta tkinter y poner un [emcv](/help/minimal-reproducible-example) que tenga solo lo relevante a la pregunta.

Comment: 2- Confio en que investigaste, pero las preguntas que no demuestran ese esfuerzo en investigar y resolver, suelen terminar cerradas. Lectura recomendada: [Te he votado negativamente porque no intentaste nada](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2874/)

Comment: Hola @DanteS. Leí el enlace y tienes toda la razón, la verdad sea dicha no investigué cómo debí hacerlo, ya que mi pc está averiada el tiempo en mi equipo actual es limitado y mi turno estaba por terminar. No quería que mi supervisor se enterara. Gracias por la respuesta y voy a quitar la etiqueta, cuando acabe, voy a mostrar la solución en mi código. Y esta situación no volverá a repetirse. Un saludo.

Comment: Entiendo, entiendo. No te sientas mal, son consejos nomás.

Answer (score 0):

Como pymysql no ofrece una forma de pasar una lista a una consulta, toca generar esa lista con formateo de cadenas. Además, el operador a usar es IN en este caso, el cual se dedica a buscar un dato en una tupla de otros datos.

> Nota: El formateo de cadenas en consultas debe ser una estrategia de ultimo recurso, ya que usar esto facilita la [inyección sql](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL)

El plan es generar, usando formateo de cadenas, una tupla conformada por `len(lista)` parametros. Luego, pasamos esos parametros donde corresponde.

```
query = "SELECT * FROM ticket WHERE fecha IN ({})".format(",".join("?" for _ in range(len(dates))))
```

Lo cual generará una consulta de este estilo:

```
SELECT * FROM ticket WHERE fecha IN (?,? ..., ?)
```

En realidad, ten en cuenta que se trata de `len(dates)` parametros, NO uno solo. Por lo que cuando pasemos la lista, en realidad tendremos que pasar su contenido a la tupla de parametros.

Lo que resulta en una tupla de este estilo:

```
(param1, param2, *dates, param3)
```

Lo cual es equivalente a:

```
(param1, param2, dates[0], dates[1], ... dates[n], param3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Hice algunos cambios para no obtener listas dentro de las listas. Aquí dejo el código definitivo que usé en mi proyecto.

```
def query():
    date_range(date1.get_date(), date2.get_date())
    fechas=dates
    print(fechas)
    conn=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="Baelca1", database="Lista_datos_Baelca")
    cursor1=conn.cursor()
    comando="SELECT * FROM ticket WHERE Fecha=%s"
    parametro=(fechas, )
    global resultado
    resultado=[]
    for date in dates:
        cursor1.execute("SELECT * FROM ticket WHERE Fecha=('{0}')".format(date))
        ticket=cursor1.fetchall()
        if ticket==[]:
            pass
        else:
            for elemento in ticket:
                resultado.append(elemento)
    print(resultado)
```

Muchas gracias.

Comment: @DanteS. Hola dante, al final no usé el formateo de cadenas, se me ocurrió usar un ciclo for para consultar cada fecha y funcionó, tal vez esto me traiga problemas más adelante cuando quiera pasar los tickets a excell, pero de momento funciona.

Comment: Ten en cuenta que no me llegan las notificaciones a menos de que haya dejado un comentario en la publicacion o sea mi publicacion (con publicacion me refiero a la pregunta o una respuesta)

Comment: Te traera problemas de rendimiento. Pues los procesos internos de mysql son mucho mas rapidos que Python. O eso tengo entendido, no soy experto en ese aspecto de las bases de datos.